# Problems with HTML5, 'for' loops, and airplanes

Tags: javascript, html, animation, html5-canvas

I am having more trouble with the webpage I am creating. I honestly have no idea what is wrong. I think it may have something to do with my 'for' loop, but I am not sure. I am trying to get a random image to animate across the canvas starting from a random x-position. I have it set up to where the random image will start at a random position, but it will not move. If someone wouldn't mind taking a quick look, that would be wonderful. Just letting you know, there may be a very simple answer to this question (source: I am very tired). Thank you for your time

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    </style>
    <script>
        var airplaneArray = [];


        function draw(){
            var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            var monoRed = document.getElementById('monoRed');
            var biRed = document.getElementById('biRed');
            var jet = document.getElementById('jet');
            var biBlue = document.getElementById('biBlue');
            var imageArray = [monoRed,biRed,jet,biBlue];

            function plane(x,y,xspeed,yspeed,source,size){
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
                this.xspeed = xspeed;
                this.yspeed = yspeed;
                this.source = source;
                this.size = size;
            }
            plane.prototype.draw = function(){
                ctx.drawImage(this.source,this.x,this.y,this.size,this.size);
            }
            plane.prototype.move = function(){
                this.x += this.xspeed;
            }

            while(airplaneArray.length-1 < 5){
                airplaneArray.push(new plane(Math.floor(Math.random()*1000),100,1,1,imageArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*4)],100),0);
            }

            ctx.save();
            ctx.clearRect(0,0,1000,500);
                ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(200,0,0,1)';
                ctx.fillRect(10,10,10,10);
                for(i=0; i < airplaneArray.length; i++){
                    airplaneArray[i].draw();
                    airplaneArray[i].move();
                }
            ctx.restore();

            var loopTimer = setTimeout('draw('+x+','+y+')',30);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="draw()">

    <canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="500"></canvas>

    <img id="monoRed" src="http://www.vaachapter11.com/images/monoplane-red.png" width="0" height="0" alt="hi" />
    <img id="biRed" src="http://www.vaachapter11.com/images/Biplane-Red.png" width="0" height="0" />
    <img id="jet" src="http://www.vaachapter11.com/images/Jet-screaming.png" width="0" height="0" />
    <img id="biBlue" src="http://www.vaachapter11.com/images/Biplane-blue.png" width="0" height="0" />
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: You're calling `draw` with parameters x and y, but the function itself doesn't have any `x` and `y` parameters defined + it's not clear where those parameters are coming from.

Comment: You also seem to be pushing a `0` into the array after each plane

Comment: What is this used for? `var loopTimer = setTimeout('draw('+x+','+y+')',30);`

Comment: Do you want the plane to move?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues in you code:

1. Remove `,0` from `airplaneArray.push(new plane(Math.floor(Math.random()*1000),100,1,1,imageArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*4)],100),0);`
2. Change setTimeout to `setTimeout('draw()',30);`

Some minor comments from me:

1. `<script>` tag should be put before `</body>` tag.
2. Move all the declaration and data preparation out of `draw()` function.
3. Should improve your algorithm to change the speed of each plane. Example: `airplaneArray.push(new plane(Math.floor(Math.random()*1000),100,Math.floor(Math.random()*20)+1,1,imageArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*4)],100));`

Comment: `setTimeout(draw, 30)` would also work and doesn't require string evaluation

Comment: For animations requestAnimationFrame is a better choice as it syncs to monitor refresh and is more efficient that setTimeout.